# Xamarin Forms Custom Page Renderer Data Bindings

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms application and I have implemented an IOS custom renderer for a content page.

I generate the page from laying out the native controls programmatically where ListEntry is a subclass of UITextField.

```
ListEntry entry = new ListEntry(control, new CGRect(x, y, width, height));
entry.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
view.AddSubview(entry);
```

I have been using two way data binding to hook up my Xamarin Form content pages to view models but I'm not sure how I go about doing this with custom renderers and native controls. I'm looking for a little guidance on the best way to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: To be honest, i have trouble getting an idea of what you are trying to do there.
Are you trying to generate native UI Elements for your content page based on the data being bound to the Xamarin.Forms content page?

If that is the case, I guess your approach might be a bit too complicated.
The idea of Xamarin.Forms is to have a shared code base for your UI and business logic so you don't have to maintain that twice.
 
Custom renderers should only take care of rendering the UI defined and executed in your shared project on the particular device.

Comment: I'm basically trying to bind native IOS controls which I create in a custom page renderer, to a view model. I can't see that there is any way to do it. I've ended up adding an event handler to the IOS control where I update the view model and for the other way, using a MessagingCenter notification to update the UI.